# One hot encode makes the my df too large, what are my alternatives considering it is a ML regression problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I need to encode the data to train a XGBRegressor model. I received a df with a large number of rows and it has a lot of categorical features, one of them is the box_id with an id code like "AAA9A8A".

The ids provide meaningful data for the prediction and are unique, if I one hot encode the data the dataset becomes too large because of the several categorical columns and unique data in them.

I've read that using the label encoder is not recommended for regression problems because it may introduce unintended relationships between categories that do not exist.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

> How should I proceed?

You should upgrade to XGBoost version 1.6 or newer. Newer XGBoost versions can handle categorical features natively, they do not need any external one-hot encoding (which is causing problems here):

```py
regressor = XGBRegressor(tree_method = "hist", enable_categorical = True)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble training the model still. The XGBoost version is 1.7.4. I created a function to train the model:
```` 
def train_model(X_train, y_train):
    """
    Train the model using the provided parameters
    """
    model = XGBRegressor(tree_method = "hist", enable_categorical = True)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    return model
````

I get an error: 
Exception has occurred: ValueError
DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category. When categorical type is supplied, The experimental DMatrix parameter`enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.

Comment: Cast your string columns into `category` data type, and it'll work.